# Download doccument on server rather than clients browser

Tags: ajax, jquery, javascript

I have made a form which converts to a PDF using jQuery. I am on a shared hosting package and as a result, cannot add any libraries such as wkhtmltopdf on to the server so in a sense am restricted.

Currently the code validates the form to ensure that the relevant areas are filled out. If filled out then submits the form.

The JS code:

```
jQuery(function($) {

var $form = $("form[name='pdf-download']"),
    $successMsg = $(".alert");
$.validator.addMethod("letters", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || value == value.match(/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/);
});
$form.validate({
    rules: {
        firstname: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 3,
            letters: true
        },
        email_id: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
    },
    messagess: {
        firstname: "Please specify your name (only letters and spaces are allowed)",
        email_id: "Please specify a valid email address"
    },
    submitHandler: function() {
        $ = jQuery;

        $("#submit").click(function() {
            alert("Submitted");
            make_product_sheet();
        });


        function make_product_sheet() {

            console.log("#submit clicked");
            var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');

            pdf.addHTML(document.getElementById("product_sheet"), function() {

                ps_filename = "generated-product-sheet";
                pdf.save(ps_filename + '.pdf');
            });
        }
    }
});
});
```

There are a few areas I am keen to sort.

Firstly - I would rather that the form was sent to the server and stored rather than being downloaded on the clients browser. I have tried adding the following code but with no joy:

```
function sendToServer() {
let pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
pdf.html(document.body, {
    callback: function (pdf) {
        let obj = {};
        obj.pdfContent = pdf.output('datauristring');
        var jsonData = JSON.stringify(obj);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/wp-content/uploads/',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: jsonData
        });
    }
});
}
```

If anyone can advise how to send the file to the back end that would be great. I know I need to use ajax to send to the back end but am fairly new to coding and unsure exactly how to implement

Ideally, If I could also initiate an email which is sent to me to advise that the pdf has been uploaded, that would be even better.

The other issue I have is that currently, I need to press the button twice to download the pdf.
It looks as though the first click validates the form and if everything is ok, the second click sends it. Ideally, I would like everything done with one click

Comment: You need to have some of this functionality in PHP for the content to be saved on the server. You should also do any serious validation of the form on the server side to prevent people from bypassing your client-side validation.

Comment: @MikeNGarrett thank you for your reply, are there any tutorials you could point me in the direction of? I honestly wouldnt know where to start with this. Ive put a lot of research into the above code but seem to have hit a wall and have no idea how to take it any further

Comment: maybe this link will be useful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29826687/storing-generated-pdf-files-on-the-server

Comment: @ChetanVaghela Thank you for that, I have looked at this post already and have tried altering it to work for me but cannot figure out how. I used the top answer as it looks most suited to my needs but struggled to get it to work. when i submit the form it took me back to homepage but could not see any errors on console

Comment: My problem is the pdf... Submitting the form is easy. But it needs to be a PDF os it is serving as a proof of delivery that I can then send to the customer to show that their goods have been signed for. The hard part os getting the form to do what I want after it has converted to pdf.

Comment: You want to use ajax in WordPress, so you need to follow this guide: https://codex.wordpress.org/Filesystem_API and https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: @MikeNGarrett I am happy with all that. My issue is sending it to the server after it has been converted to PDF. I seem to be able to send it to the server as plain text or convert to PDF. trying to get the send to follow the conversion is my issue

Comment: You cannot send it straight to the uploads directory. You must process via `admin-ajax.php`. PHP has to be involved.

Comment: @MikeNGarrett I appreciate that. but then comes my predicament of combining PHP and JS and getting them to work together. The easiest option would be using wkhtmltopdf but I am unable to add this library to my server as I am on shared hosting.

Comment: Javascript and PHP work fine together in WordPress. codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins. If you want to render the PDF on the server side, there are plenty of PHP libraries to accomplish this.

Comment: If you're doing this with jQuery then the PDF is generated entirely within the browser. You'd want to upload it to the server, not download it. Making an AJAX request to `wp-content/uploads` makes no sense though, if you could do that then hackers could do the same thing and upload anything they wanted to your site. You need to do a file upload via javascript, and you need something at the server end to recieve the file. Eitherway it's much, much easier to just do this in PHP, seriously consider it, there are security implications to what you're asking for

Comment: Additionally, why store the PDF on the server at all? Just store what was in the form and generate a new PDF in JS when the user wants to view it again. PDFs can contain dangerous things, you don't want to just allow uploading of any PDF to your server

Comment: @TomJNowell , In all honesty, I am not too bothered whether the pdf is saves to my server or emailed to me, as long as the PDF comes to me and is not downloaded on to the users device. I have made a fiddle of my script so that you can see what it is/does - https://jsfiddle.net/SupGen/paufgsd9/ The form is to be used by a freight company who subcontracts drivers. Essentially the company gets a job from their client, they sub contracat a driver and send a link to this form. The form should then be brought up on the drivers phone and given to the recipient to sign. The form should then,

Comment: the form should then be submitted and received by the freight company. currently the form is downloaded on to the drivers device and they need to rely on the driver remembering to forward them the form which can cause a lot of unnecessary chasing up.